# sorting by high-low price with mysql data

Tags: php, html, mysql

Here's what I have, and what I want to do:

I have 12 items in my MySql database. 4 products are 4.99, 4 products are 3.99 and 4 products are 2.99.

I realize I can query the database like this, and It will give me a list of products at that price:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM UFPProducts WHERE price = 4.99";
$results = mysql_query ($query, $connect);

while ($row = @ mysql_fetch_array($results))
{

print



"<div id= 'item'>" .

"<p>Product id ".$row["ProductID"]."</p>".
"<p><img src=".$row["Image"]."></p>".
"<p>&pound".$row["Price"]."</p>".
"<p>".$row["Description"]."</p>".

"</div>";
}

?>
```

However, what I want, is a button I can press to sort products by price.

What's a simple way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM UFPProducts order by price ASC";
```

The above query will list all price in ascending order. But if you want to have distinct price  grouped together, use the below query.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM UFPProducts group by price order by price ASC";
```

Comment: thankyou very much for the code.

    $query = "SELECT * FROM UFPProducts group by price order by price ASC";

The code above gives me 1 product only from each price group.


The code below gives me products from every category in every category by price:

    $query = "SELECT * FROM UFPProducts order by price ASC";

Comment: So which one you need ? The second one ?

Comment: the one I needed was this one:

$query = "SELECT * FROM UFPProducts order by price ASC";

That works like a dream. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a button that executes a new query, and then output those new results.

First write a the new query: probably something along the lines of `"SELECT * FROM UFPProducts ORDER BY price DESC";`.

Then build the UI in HTML that the visitor will use sort by price.  A simple solution would be a link to a new page which runs the new query.  You could use AJAX to provide a more elegant solution.

Last, display the results of the new query; probably by re-using your existing print statements.